# Mysql copy data from one column to another and modify

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `product` with a column `name` now I created a new field `slug` and I want to fill all the slugs with the `name` column value but replace all white spaces with dashes

This is what i've tried:

```
INSERT INTO product (slug)
select REPLACE(name, ' ', '-') from product
```

I get no errors but my slug field is still empty

Comment: I get the distinct feeling this should be an `UPDATE product SET slug = REPLACE(name, ' ', '-')`

Comment: You shouldn't do that anyway, copying data from one place to another will typically end up with data inconsistency. Create a view instead, and you will always have consistent data. (Do newer MySQL versions have computed columns?)

Comment: Seems like you should have a _virtual column_ here!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a generated column:

```
alter table product add column slug varchar(255) 
    generated always as (replace(name, ' ', '-')) stored;
```

The value would automatically be updated, which is a big convenience.

If you want to do a one-time update, it would be:

```
update product
    set slug = replace(name, ' ', '-');
```